# Updating a property through wpf datagrid in a collection through the individual element

Tags: c#, wpf, object, properties, binding

Ok here: source xaml in question, in ucPacketPrinting.xaml

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                        x:Name="clmPrint"
                        Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Header="Print"
                        HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle2}" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Next, here’s the vmPacketOrder object class Property. The column "clmPrint" is bound to this I believe

```
private bool isSelected = false;
…
public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => isSelected;
            set {
                Set(value, x => isSelected);
            }
        }
```

Finally here’s the vmPacketPrinting in question. This uses a collection of vmPacketOrder objects. rowCountSelected is bound to a textbox that displays the number of selected rows. I’ve gotten some other parts of it worked out, only thing that’s left is actually updating the rowCountSelected property when a checkbox in the column is checked. I guess I could have it check the isSelected property for every item in the collection on a timer and update it that way, but it’d be much better if I could just have an event that updates it when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. I haven't found a way to really do this so far.

```
private ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder> packetOrders;
…
public ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder> PacketOrders
        {
            get {
                return packetOrders;
            }
            set => Set(value ?? new ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder>(), x => packetOrders);
        }
…
public string rowCountSelected { get; set; } = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the `PacketOrders` property is set to a new `ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder>`, you should hook up an event handler for all individual `vmPacketOrder` objects:

```
private ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder> packetOrders;
public ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder> PacketOrders
{
    get
    {
        return packetOrders;
    }
    set
    {
        if (packetOrders != null)
            foreach (var packetOrder in packetOrders)
                packetOrder.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;

        Set(value ?? new ObservableCollection<vmPacketOrder>(), x => packetOrders);

        if (packetOrders != null)
            foreach (var packetOrder in packetOrders)
                packetOrder.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(vmPacketOrder.IsSelected))
        rowCountSelected = packetOrders.Count(x => x.IsSelected);
}
```

This will cause the `rowCountSelected` to get set whenever the `IsSelected` property of a `vmPacketOrder` is set.

If items may be added to the `PacketOrders` collection dynamically, you should also [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44239220/7252182) the `CollectionChanged` event and hook up event handlers to added items and remove event handlers from removed events as well.